# Error while loading parquet format on the basis of date or size or required size format from s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyarrow

I am trying to load parquet file format data from s3 in a filtered fashion, by loading few MB or load it on the basis of date

code:

```
    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_path1, 
    Range=f'bytes=0-1048576')

    filters = [('date', '>=', start_date), ('date', '<=', end_date)]

    body = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())

    df = pd.read_parquet((body), engine='pyarrow', filters=filters)
```

Error while reading pd.read_parquet:

```
    ArrowInvalid: Could not open Parquet input source '': Parquet 
    magic bytes not found in footer.
```

do help with any solutions if possible

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your question and replace the images with text. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557